# Some users have no data sources but have data in Google Fit app

Tags: rest, google-fit

My team has published an app that retrieves users' Google Fit data using the REST API to display how active they are and grade their fitness level. I'm interested in the steps and active_minutes metrics.

About 50% of our users have either no data sources or limited data sources. Some of these users are on my team and I have verified they have accepted the required scopes and that the Fit app is indeed recording data.

To test users, I am refreshing their access token (which works fine) and then calling this endpoint to retrieve a list of available data sources:
GET fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources (https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list)

Sometimes the datasources will be an empty array, and sometimes it will have a very limited number of data sources (ex. data sources involving calories, but not steps, even though steps are showing up just fine in Fit).

I am requesting the following scopes:
fitness.activity.read
fitness.body.write

The other 50% of our users work just fine and I am completely stumped at what is different about the users that appear to have no (or limited) data sources.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that those users are in fact lizard people. No, in all seriousness, how should we know?

Comment: In a general sense, if a user sees step and activity data in their Google Fit app, shouldn't we expect there to exist a corresponding data source? Why would a user not have this data source, for example: "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"? I don't understand what causes some users to have this data source, and others to not. Does it depend on the phone? This seems like a data source that every user should have, especially if they see step data in their Fit app.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) when you say "sometimes", do you mean that an individual user will see their data sources in one request but not the next; or that one user always sees the data sources whereas another user does not? 2) did you notice this start to happen on any particular date?

Comment: 3) what is the exact request you are issuing on the dataSources/list page? (Tip: the try it now supports direct linking; enter your request in the page then copy the URL in here; e.g. [this](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list?apix_params=%7B"userId"%3A"me"%7D) works for me)

Comment: @AndyTurner - 1) The latter - I can collect data just fine for some users in our database, but for others, there are no available data sources, or only a few data sources not relating to steps / active_minutes which is what we're interested in. For example, I see one user who has data sources related to calories_expended only, even though the Fit app is indeed recording steps. 2) No, there is no date where this problem started happening. 3) I am calling the list endpoint without any parameters. So, simply a GET request of "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that some users had syncing disabled for Google Fit. To enable syncing you must go into the Settings app of your Android phone:

Settings -> Accounts -> Select your Google account being used for Google Fit -> Ensure that Google Fit is enabled for syncing.

This answers the most puzzling case where we had users with some data sources, but not all of the expected data sources such as estimated steps. I presume the limited data sources available were from a short time period before syncing was disabled, or while the user was using an outdated version of Google Fit. I'm also finding users with more obvious problems, like using OAuth with a Google account different than the one connected to Google Fit.